# SQL Simulating a foreach

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have to insert 7 rows into a table for each row found in a another table, I am currently doing this is my C# application, but it is dreadfully slow for a relatively small database.

I want to move this into one query, and the best method would be a foreach loop, SQL doesnt have this though so a WHILE loop will have to do.

However I cant even get to the insert part as I cannot loop through the rows, here is my SQL so far

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;

SELECT ResNo FROM Res WHERE TSGrNo = 1;

print 'row cnt';
print @@RowCount; -- prints 0 even though 6 rows are returned

WHILE @cnt < @@Rowcount
BEGIN
     print @cnt;
     --In here I need to do this
     -- INSERT INTO tbl (_,tbl.ResNo,_, _, _)
        -- VALUES (_,Row.ResNo,_,_,_)
     SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END
```

Does anyone know a better and working way to do this?

EDIT:

This is where I am at now

```
DECLARE @_R1 INT = 7, @_Date INT = 20150608

SELECT  *
FROM    Res r
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  * 
        FROM    Vis_ResR rr
        WHERE   rr.ResNo = r.ResNo
        AND rr.Date = @_Date
        )
AND r.TSGrNo = 1
AND r.R1 = @_R1

INSERT INTO Vis_ResR (R1, ResNo, Vis_ResR.Date, FrTm, ToTm)
VALUES (@_R1,r.ResNo,@_Date,0,0)
```

@_R1 and @_Date will be set before sending the query, I just don't understand how to make it INSERT using the r.ResNo values

Comment: Try to avoid solving SQL/database problems with object oriented programming techniques (loops, foreach, iterations, etc). RDBMS require set based operations to be most efficient. Can you please supply your table definitions, a sample of the data, and what you would like the output to look like?

Comment: Sorry I don't have time to write up an answer here, but this question may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852782/t-sql-loop-over-query-results

Comment: I understand that loops etc isn't the norm, but in this case I believe it is the correct thing to do... ResNo is an int, and is the only thing I need to get from each row inside the Res table. I then need to insert into another table using the ResNo as the second value.

Comment: So... are you using SQL-Server or MySQL?

Comment: I am using SQLServer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why you cannot use `SELECT` statement in the `INSERT INTO`?

```sql
INSERT INTO tbl (tbl.ResNo)
SELECT ResNo FROM Res WHERE TSGrNo = 1
```

If `SELECT` statement return 6 rows, then 6 rows will be inserted

[Adding Rows by Using INSERT and SELECT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188263(v=sql.105).aspx)

*Update after comment:*
Inserting values if not already exist
Based on the version of SQL server you can use `MERGE`

```sql
DECLARE @_R1 INT = 7 
DECLARE @_Date INT = 20150608

MERGE INTO Vis_ResR AS Target
USING (SELECT ResNo 
       FROM Res 
       WHERE TSGrNo = 1 AND R1 = @_R1) AS Source 
ON Target.ResNo = Source.ResNo
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (R1, ResNo, Vis_ResR.Date, FrTm, ToTm) 
    VALUES (@_R1, Source.ResNo, @_Date, 0, 0);
```

[MERGE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

Or if your SQL server version older then 2008 then try next

```sql
DECLARE @_R1 INT = 7
DECLARE @_Date INT = 20150608

INSERT INTO Vis_ResR (R1, ResNo, Vis_ResR.Date, FrTm, ToTm) 
SELECT @_R1, r.ResNo, @_Date, 0, 0
FROM Res r 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM Vis_ResR rr 
                  WHERE rr.ResNo = r.ResNo 
                  AND rr.Date = @_Date ) 
AND r.TSGrNo = 1 
AND r.R1 = @_R1
```

Comment: Hurm, I didn't think of this. Would this also work with an IF statement? as I only need to INSERT if a row with the ResNo doesn't already exist

Comment: @TedJames It would work if you filter out the rows from the `SELECT` statement, using `NOT EXISTS` for example)

Comment: @Fabio this is where I am up on now.... `DECLARE @_R1 INT = 7, @_Date INT = 20150608

SELECT  *
FROM    Res r
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  * 
        FROM    Vis_ResR rr
        WHERE   rr.ResNo = r.ResNo
        AND rr.Date = @_Date
        )
AND r.TSGrNo = 1
AND r.R1 = @_R1

INSERT INTO Vis_ResR (R1, ResNo, Vis_ResR.Date, FrTm, ToTm)
VALUES (@_R1,r.ResNo,@_Date,0,0)`

Comment: @TedJames, just replace `VALUES` with your `SELECT` query with columns ordered like in the `INSERT`. Check updated answer with your data sample

Comment: @Fabio thanks very much! The last sql code works perfect for me.