# SQL query and Email SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Would someone please help me to write a SQL SP that would query two tables and email the people in the second column of the TableB. The structure of the tables are as below:

**TableA**

```
ColumnA(Pkey) ColumnB (Identical Column to ColumnA of the TableB)
-----------------------
Value1        ValueB1                     
Value2        ValueB2
Value3        ValueB3
Value4        ValueB1
Value5        ValueB1
```

**TableB**

```
ColumnA       ColumnB
-----------------------
ValueB1       User1
ValueB2       User2
ValueB3       User3
```

Email Format for User1:

```
Dear User1,

"Below are your query results:"

    ColumnA(From TableA)   ColumnB(From TableB)
    Value1                 ValueB1 
    Value4                 ValueB1
    Value5                 ValueB1
```

And the same email to the remaining usersB and C which corresponds to the values in TableA and TableB.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Please disregard. I just made two SPs. One with the sp_send_dbmail and included the Parameters and the 2nd SP to query the list values from Table B and pass them to the store Procedure I made for the sp_send_dbmail. This code by XN16 is gold!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11852882/3314399