# How to loop in Sql Server and update a certain column?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have records in my Sql Server 2008 table, I need to update the field TranTime. 
How can I do it using a loop? Evey iteration should insert/update a unique time.

I don't know the syntax/approach. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: you can loop using cursor but its not advisable! So one possible solution is to get all the affected records and perform an update query with the destination table and the results table, this is more efficient than cursor

Comment: I think cursor is what I needed.

Comment: yes but also consider other scenarios like if the there are millions of records in the database

Comment: Here is an example for a cursor based solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852782/t-sql-loop-over-query-results Here is an example for a solution using the T-SQL `while` method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487546/do-while-loop-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: I guess it will cause a slow performance or even a problem in the database. But in my records it's just 50 records.

Comment: @Ralph: Thanks for the reference, I might use the second reference. thanks!

Comment: Looping/Cursors are almost always the worst solution, SQL databases are designed for set based operations and if its possible to use one you almost always should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with this solution

```
    DECLARE @ID INT
    DECLARE @T int
    DECLARE @Time time(7)
    SET @ID = 2
    set @T = 80005836 //Around 8:AM

    WHILE (@ID <=15) //I want to update 15 rows only
    BEGIN


   SELECT (@T / 1000000) % 100 as hour,
          (@T / 10000) % 100 as minute,
          (@T / 100) % 100 as second,
          (@T % 100) * 10 as millisecond


   SET @Time = 
   (
   SELECT dateadd(hour, (@T / 1000000) % 100,
   dateadd(minute, (@T / 10000) % 100,
   dateadd(second, (@T / 100) % 100,
   dateadd(millisecond, (@T % 100) * 10, cast('00:00:00' as time(2)))))) AS Time 
   )

     UPDATE myTable
     SET TranTime = @Time
     WHERE ID = @ID
    //increment ctr for ID and add 1 hour for a Time
    SET @ID = @ID + 1
    SET @T = @T + 1000000
    END
    GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Update statement by using `DateTime.Now`:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update yourTableName set TranTime = @dt",yourConnection);
SqlParameter parameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@dt", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
parameter.Value = DateTime.Now;
```

If you want to update it by time only and unique you could use `TimeOfDay`. Like this:

```
DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay
```

Or `ToLongTimeString` like this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()
```

Based on your needs.

Comment: Hi, I think it's a date stamp not a time. . .how to insert it by time stamp and unique, like increment by one every insert? thanks!

Comment: @FrancisSaul...You could use `TimeOfDay`. Like this: `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay` or `ToLongTimeString` like this: `DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()`.