# SSMS "SELECT * INTO" from MSSQL Table to a Linked MySQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssms

I need to transfer some tables from a MSSQL server to a MySQL server.

I have successfully connected SSMS on a windows host to my MySQL server on my linux box. The "linked server" appears in the object explorer and I am able to perform queries on the MySQL server, vis.

`sql
select * from openquery(LINKED_SERVER_NAME, "select * from mysqltable.customers");`

I'm an utter noob with MSSQL and am somewhat confused by openquery. Is the query "read only", or can I actually select the contents of an MSSQL table into a table on the linked server?

All the MSDN pages I have read are reminiscent of those old break dancing instruction videos from the 80's. I.E. a very terse example, followed by utter madness.

I have seen excellent examples showing how to use openquery to select the contents of the **remote** MySQL database into an MSSQL database. Unfortunately I can't figure out if there is a way to reverse that syntax.

Really sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm just not getting any traction.

Comment: http://mohtasebi.com/sql/2011/12/10/linking-mysql-and-sql-server-using-linked-server.html

Comment: The job is done on MSSQL.

Comment: I'm going to have to stare at the screen for a while.

Comment: AFAIK there is no OPENQUERY for MySql.

Comment: It is becoming apparent that in your insert example, one has to do an "empty" query that returns the fieldnames you wish to insert. This is a convoluted mess (SSMS, not your example). I'll definitely show my work for the next guy. This is awful.

Answer (score 0):

## Slow and Probably Awful Answer

Using the clues provided by [@McNets / Amir Mohtasebi](http://mohtasebi.com/sql/2011/12/10/linking-mysql-and-sql-server-using-linked-server.html) and [@bluefeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852782/t-sql-loop-over-query-results) I have been able to kludge something together.

I punted on trying to directly copy the MSSQL table into the MySQL database. I'm still not clear on whether it is even a possibility with openquery.

### Loop Over Query Results and Insert Records One-By-One

```
declare @i int=0
declare @count int
declare @idcustomer int
declare @customerType int 

select @count = count(*) from customers

while (@i < @count)
begin
    select @idcustomer = idCustomer, @customerType = customerType from customers
    order by idcustomer asc offset @i rows fetch next 1 rows only

    insert openquery(
        REMOTE_STORE,
        'select idcustomer, customerType from customers where 1=0'
    ) values(
        @idcustomer,
        @customerType)

    set @i = @i + 1;
end
```

As one would expect, this takes just south of forever, and requires set-up for each and every field. If anyone has a better technique (and that is probably **anyone** who uses T-SQL), I'd sure love to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you just try the basic queries in the syntax of:

> select * **into newtable** from openquery(LINKED_SERVER_NAME, "select * from mysqltable.customers");

OR

> select * **into newtable** from [linkedserver].[database].[schema].[tablename]

Comment: That's where I went first, but you will always be my Fujiko.