# If else in SQL Server with multiple insert statements

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert, case-when

```
select 
    din, driv_height, city, Driver_Addres_Posta_Code, DRIV_GENDER_ID 
from 
    driv_testing 

if DRIV_GENDER_ID IN ('M', 'F') 
begin
    insert into driv_success
end
else DRIV_GENDER_ID not in ('M', 'F')
begin 
    insert into error_logs (error_description) 
    values ('Gender fails')
end
```

I have one source table `driv_testing` and sink table `driv_success` and `error_logs` table to log bad records.

If `DRIV_GENDER_ID IN ('M', 'F')`  then I want to insert into `driv_success` otherwise insert into `error_logs` table..

But I am getting error for the above query.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow! Your question is not well asked, please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please tag your request with the DBMS you are using (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, ...). In order to answer SQL questions, it is usually necessary to know the DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't tagged your DBMS and I don't recognize the syntax you are trying to apply. But generally inserts into different tables require separate statements. Something along the lines of:

```
insert into driv_success (din)
select din
from driv_testing
where driv_gender_id in ('M', 'F');

insert into error_logs (din, error_description) 
select din, 'Gender fails'
from driv_testing
where driv_gender_id not in ('M', 'F');
```

Comment: Actually i want to have multiple insert staements using if else or case when

Comment: You are selecting all rows of table `driv_testing` and then you ask `if DRIV_GENDER_ID IN('M','F')`. Which row would this condition be referring to? You would have to **loop** through your `driv_testing` rows instead (if your DBMS provides this - you still haven't told us which DBMS you are using). But this would probably be much slower then my approach with just two insert statements.

Comment: My requirement is in azure data factory copy activity I want to move source data to two tables if record is good(pass all condition like gender must be M or F and postal code should follow particular alphanumeric format) then those records should enter into driv_success table and if record fails due to  any condition mismatch it should go into error_log table and it should happen at a time.So I wanted to use if else query statement in copy activity source side instead of giving dataset pointing to a particular table.

Comment: In SQL Server you can use a stored procedure where you loop over your query results (a cursor loop): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852782/t-sql-loop-over-query-results